# Any commands that will change the keyboard?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcuts, ubuntu-mate

I speak multiple languages (English, Bulgarian, Greek, and Japanese) And I was wondering if there were any keyboard shortcut commands that I can add that will go through all of the languages when I press said keyboard shortcut keys. (I use Ubuntu Mate BTW)

Comment: Do you mean user interface language or keyboard layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Keyboard Preferences ( where you put the layouts that you want to 
use) there's a button "Options...", there is a list with several items, one of them is "Key(s) to change keyboard layout".

Comment: Yes I know but I want a key command that I can add through System->Control Center->Hardware->Keyboard Shortcuts. And then adding it through there